# Why won't my HTML render?

Tags: html, google-visualization

I have compared the script below to that in the google charts documentation at the following site:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart

But it does not render. I cannot find anything wrong with this code. Is there something else I should be looking for?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1.0", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['sepal_width', 'sepal_length'], 
                [3.5,5.1],
                [3.0,4.9],
                [3.2,4.7],
                [3.1,4.6],
                [3.6,5.0],
                [3.9,5.4],
                [3.4,4.6],
                [3.4,5.0],
                [2.9,4.4],
                [3.1,4.9],
                [3.7,5.4]
                ]);
    var options = {
        title: 'Edgar Anderson's Iris Data',
        hAxis: {title: 'Petal Length', minValue: 0, maxValue: 7},
        vAxis: {title: 'Petal Width', minValue: 0, maxValue: 3},
        legend: 'none'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JS syntax errors? `title: 'Edgar Anderson's Iris Data'`. Count the quotes. Try to figure out why this is a problem. Once you figure that out, and check your JS console, you might just get something working.

Comment: Thanks - I made this change throughout, but still have formatting issues. I will keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

```
title: 'Edgar Anderson's Iris Data',
```

needs to be:

```
title: "Edgar Anderson's Iris Data",
```

Comment: I must have had some sort of spacing error (??) as I started from scratch and managed to get it going. Thanks the tips!

Comment: it wasn't the spaing a spacing error with what you posted here.. you was trying to encapsulate a ' using ' '  if you have ' in your string wrap the string with " " or use a backslash to escape the '